# How can i Set up my own business idea and token

Tags: transfer, network, exchange

I'm new to the EOS world, I have a business idea and want to build my own project on EOS so I want to build my own network, my own token that is also built on a modified EOS.token.
But I would like to remain compatible with EOS mainnet.
Is it possible or not?
do I have to fork or is it enough to quit as a block producer?
I would like to have the opportunity to swap my token for EOS in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible to spin up an EOSIO chain yourself.  You do not have to use the EOS mainnet's existing balance as a snapshot for your new chain, you could start fresh.  Atomic swapping is possible with LiquidApps's LiquidBridge or with a centralized solution.

Though this is more a place for tech related questions good resources would be:

Our telegram or another community telegram to point you in the right direction

- https://t.me/LiquidAppsOfficial
- https://t.me/Everything_EOS
- https://t.me/EOSNation

EOSIO Dev channel for dev related questions: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Welcome to EOS!!